# make query strings visible

Tags: jquery

I am doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: this.href,
    async: true,
    data: $('form').first().serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: 'Please wait ...' });
    },
    complete: function() {
    $.unblockUI();
    },
    success: function(result) {
    $("#grid").replaceWith($("#grid", result));
    },
    dataType: "text"
});
```

Is it possible to show the query strings obtained from the form so that the user can store the link?

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just pre-calculate the serialized form:

```
var the_data = $('form').first().serialize();
$.ajax({
    type      : 'GET',
    url       : this.href,
    async     : true,
    data      : the_data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: 'Please wait ...' });
    },
    complete  : function() {
        $.unblockUI();
    },
    success   : function(result) {
        $("#grid").replaceWith($("#grid", result));

        // Based on your comment, I am alerting `the data` to clarify
        // the example.  Obviously you'll want to display this on the page
        // rather than using an alert.
        alert(the_data);
    },
    dataType  : "text"
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @csetzkorn do you see the comment in the success function?  You have to take the variable, `the_data` and display it.  I didn't bother spelling it out because I don't know your DOM.  I'll update with an alert message so you see my point.

Comment: I was wondering about that. I would like to add it to the url. I can remeber there was a query string plugin but havent touched jquery for a long time. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just save `$('form').first().serialize()` as a variable.

```
var query = $('form').first().serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: this.href,
    data: query,
    ...
    success: function(result){
      //you can use query in here...
    }
    ...
});
```